# Manipulating value of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, stored-procedures, bootstrap-4

TestController.php

```
    $data = array(
        'name'=>"Micko Dela Sample",
        'm1' => "Email Subject",
        'm2' => $request->message //this is the checkbox and has a value of "one two three" and "four five six" take note this is an array
    );

    Mail::send('emails.mail', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
      $message->to('mickojel.delarosa@gmail.com', 'Micko Dela Rosa')->subject
          ($data['m1']);
       $message->from('xyz@gmail.com','Micko Main Machine');
    });
    echo "HTML Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
```

email.php

```
   @foreach($m2 as $m)
  <p>
  {

   <br>
   "Value": "$m",
   <br>
  }

  </p>
  <br>
  @endforeach
```

the output is: 
1 2 3
4 5 6

but is there a way that I can display the output like...
first number is: $m->1
second number is: $m->2
…. on so on

I tried using explode and implode but still no luck.

Comment: where is `$m2` define? where is the explode? can you please provide simple and run-able code example that failed?

Comment: Please  provide all details so that we can understand posted question clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it now to make things clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error String to array conversaion, is because you're trying to output or manipulate a variable like a string, witch is array.
To know that you can [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) the variable to check what is inside. Additionaly you can also use [is_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function to check if the variable is actually an array.